# Why am I frequently getting disconnected from wifi after some time of use?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04, realtek

I use a Lenovo g50-45 with Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter. I am connected to the wifi and can access the Internet for like 10-5 min and then the wifi will still be connected but there will be no Internet.
Here are some details and analysis report's [wireless-info.txt](http://pasted.co/50dfa971)

Comment: For the first command it says "rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf’: No such file or directory
" @Pilot6..Can I continue

Comment: Yes, you can. That command was needed in case that file had been created in attempts to fix it another way.